# How to empty() on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to empty an h2 element when a button is clicked. I do this in part of my code already and it works fine, but when I try to empty this part of my code it doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

[JSFiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyLohgk2/)

```
 $('#help').click(function() {
    $('#intro').empty();
    $('#intro').text("News:");
    $('#help').hide();
    $('#noHelp').hide();
    $('#news').text("Battle system created");
   });
```

This part is breaking it and I don't know why

```
var fly = new Monster("fly", 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1);
var mouse = new Monster("mouse", 2, 3, 10, 2, 1, 2);
var rat = new Monster("rat", 4, 5, 20, 4, 2, 2);
var rabidChihuahua = new Monster("chihuahua", 6, 8, 35, 6, 1, 4);
var bulldog = new Monster("bulldog", 10, 14, 60, 10, 4, 1);
var wolf = new Monster("Wolf", 15, 18, 65, 12, 3, 6);
var vampie = new Monster("Vampire", 20, 23, 100, 12, 5, 4);
var werewolf = new Monster("Werewolf", 25, 29, 100, 14, 3, 9);
var giantSlime = new Monster("Giant Slime", 31, 38, 200, 7, 15, 1);
var babyDragon = new Monster("Baby Dragon", 39, 50, 150, 16, 9, 5);
var orc = new Monster("Orc", 50, 64, 220, 10, 12, 4);
var succubi = new Monster("Succubi", 61, 80, 190, 21, 8, 12);
var elderDragon = new Monster("Elder Dragon", 75, 100, 300, 21, 15, 8);
var sanaan = new Monster("Sanaan", 150, 500, 500, 55, 45, 30);
```

Comment: are you creating the button html dynamically? using ajax or something?

Comment: I make the button in the html.

Comment: Check your console, you have a javascript error.

Comment: could you show me where? I rand this through the console and jshint and came up with no errors

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` on `monsterList.appendChild(opt);`. Looks like `monsterList` is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle :

> [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyLohgk2/4/)

I've changed this line to test the opt var :

```
if(opt.length > 0){
    monsterList.appendChild(opt); // appending option to select element
}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixes it. Could you explain why that part would be breaking my button code when it didn't break any of the other code under it?

Comment: When a JS error is encountered, it stops execution of the code. So when you click on the button with a JS error in your code which is below, it doesn't works because your function is below the other one which has an error. If you put it above, it works.